# Java and MySQL is not successfully connected

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have an issue regarding on connecting to MySQL from my Java Database connection in Eclipse. I used the latest connector mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar. On the other hand my database in MySQL has no password so I decided to leave it blank after username "root" (e.g."") correct me if I am wrong. Attached is my code and a screenshot. Please let me know what to do and many thanks for all the help.

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %><%@ page import="java.io.*" %><%@ page import="com.mysql.*" %><?xml version="1.0"?>
<tours>
<%
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet result = null;

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tours", "root", "");
        out.println("connected to database");
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        out.println("error connecting to database");
    }
%>
</tours>
```

Comment: what is the exception you are getting? please post the exception trace to get the precise help.

Comment: No need to call newInstance();

Comment: use e.printStackTrace()  to print exception

Comment: You're explicitly discarding the exception in the catch block that would tell you *exactly* what the problem is.

Comment: This is what I got: 
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tours> connected to database </tours> However the xml tag are still there instead of the phrase "connected to database" Though it is now connected, I feel that there is something wrong with my code. By the way, I'm using jdk7. Thanks Juned

Comment: then it is connected! why the hell you said _"..is not successfully connected"_ ?

Comment: Have you tried removing `.newInstance()` ? And Post the stacktrace for better answer.

Comment: @Blueapples So, it's doing *exactly what it's supposed to*. If you don't want `<tours></tours>` why do you have it in your jsp?

Comment: Here is the code I got after running to Apache Tomcat ` <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <tours> connected to database </tours>` There is still a tag of xml in a browser. Is it okay? @DnR I really don't know why it is now connected. Before it is not. I know it is now off the topic. However, I just want to get rid the xml tag in the browser. @Brian Roach I just wanted to test if the video tutorial is correct or not and I have information to the MySQL database. Yes I deleted the `.newInstance()` and it is still the same.

Comment: I think I need to move on to the next tutorials as long as the web browser interprets it as connected to the browser even there is a xml tag. Thanks a lot guys for your patience answering my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.*" %><%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<tours>
    <%
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet result = null;

try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tours", "root", "");
    out.println("connected to database");
}
catch(SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(e);
}
%>
</tours>
```

According to me there is no need to use newInstance() Method. Probably you should use a password with mysql. and use e.printStackTrace() method in catch block so that you can know what is going wrong with your code. There might be conflict between java.sql.* and com.mysql.*. Use java.sql.* for connectivity to mysql database.

Comment: `catch(SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(e);
}` gaves me an error without this code `out.println("error connecting to database");` inserted on the catch block.

Comment: then use master class, catch(Exception e){ out.println(e); }. Using this you can get any exception occured in your code. Please let me know why vote down?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. I didn't vote down. I vote for your answer. It helps a lot. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

1 check the SQLException by using printStackTrace, there should contain more details information.

2 make sure you allow loclhost connection on mysql db, it depends on the privileges, sometimes you may need to use your localhost IP address, try it too.

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that when you tried to view the result without showing the xml tag on the internal browser from Eclipse Indigo, just copy the URL (e.g. localhost:8080/jsp_final/data.jsp) and paste it to your default computer browser (e.g. Firefox, Chrome, IE, Opera, and Safari). There you can also view source the xml data coming from the phpMyAdmin by right clicking to your browser and choose "View Source".

Comment: And on this end, you see the view source of the file on the eclipse built in browser. By the way, I'm using windows platform. Thanks.